# Iframe onload event when content is set from srcdoc

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can i specify an onload property for an iframe loaded from `srcdoc` attribute. For example:

```
<iframe id="Content" runat="server" srcdoc="Large HTML contents that are set from the server"></iframe>
```

I'm using asp.net webforms to populate the content from another server.

However, the normal way to trigger onload for an iframe would be the following, but that won't work:

```js
$(function () {

    var iframe = document.getElementById(DocumentViewer.GetFrameClientID());

    console.log({iframe}) // OK

    iframe.onload = function () { // Never Trigger unless i add a src attribute instead of srcdoc
        console.log('loaded')
    }
})
```

I found an issue reported on github in 2018 ["load" event handler is called prematurely for iframe.srcdoc](https://github.com/t2ym/thin-hook/issues/243)

Any clue?

Comment: Same issue here, did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: @pinhead not really

Answer (score 0):

the closest thing i've come up with is to call something like this after init.

```
const interval = setInterval(function() {
      var iFrameID = <HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById('Content');

      if(iFrameID) {
        let newheight = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        iFrameID.style.height = newheight;

      } 
    }, 200);
```

This sets the iframe height to match that of the iframe's content every 2ms. This function will not terminate and I have not yet found a good stopping condition.